# How can I edit __setattr__ to raise an error when class object is attempted to have a new attribute store but still allow some use

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out a way, using `__setattr__`, in my class to raise an error when it is called or used, but at the same time allow for it's use inside the class in places like `__init__`. Is there any way I can either write specific exceptions under `__setattr__` to allow certain instances to work or a total way anything inside the class will work?

Here is the idea that I have been working with:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, test_list):
        self.p = test_list

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'p':
            pass
        else:
            raise AssertionError('Object can not add any new attributes.')
```

I do not know what I could do in place of the pass, as I would like to use `__setattr__` in the original manner in that conditions. Any way I can make exceptions to allow for this to work?

Comment: You could use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) if you wanted an immutable object. You mention allowing updates in specific methods outside of `__init__` though, can you give examples of this?

Comment: The main issue I run into immediate is with self. statements. While a tuple would be great for immutability, it my case it would not work as the problem I am trying to solve deals with a list of dictionaries specifically.

Comment: How about a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) with `frozen=True`? Would give you your "immutable" class without the restrictions of a tuple

Comment: I think my issue is my restriction is to use __setattr__ to raise an error if it is used but still allow for all of the functions I have set up previously to work, with self. being the most prevalent issue.

Comment: What are you *actually trying to accomplish*?

Comment: Just have `__setattr__` always raise an error. Then in `__init__`, use `object.__setattr__(self, 'p', test_list)`. Of course, *anyone* can use `object.__setattr__` to circumvent your "immutability", but that is always the case in Python

Comment: Thank you, i'll see if that helps. I managed to figure out everything else, just this final part made me realize I do not understand __setattr__ fully.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "the last part"?